# Specify interface member not by name but type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, interface

I have a lot of similar classes generated by svcutil from some external WSDL file. Any class has a `Header` property and `string` property which named `class name + "1"`.

For instance, I have classes: `SimpleRequest` that has `Header` property and `SimpleRequest1` property.
Another one is `ComplexRequest` that has `Header` property and `ComplexRequest1` property.

So, I want to create a common interface for such classes. So, basically I can define something like that:

```
interface ISomeRequestClass {
  string Header;
  // here is some definition for `class name + "1"` properties...
}
```

Is it possible to define such member in interface?

---

*Here is post edit goes...*

Here is sample of generated class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class SimpleRequest
{


    public string Header;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="SimpleRequest", Namespace="data", Order=0)]
    public SimpleRequestMsg SimpleRequest1;

    public SimpleRequest()
    {
    }

    public SimpleRequest(string Header, SimpleRequestMsg SimpleRequest1)
    {
        this.Header = Header;
        this.SimpleRequest1 = SimpleRequest1;
    }
}
```

---

**POST EDIT 2**

I changed definition of this annoying +1 property to represent real actual picture. It's all has different class types. So how can I pull it out to common interface?

---

**POST EDIT 3**

Here is [coupled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410917/reorganize-classes-structure) that could bring more clarify.

Comment: Are you able to edit these classes?

Comment: I can edit generated classes, but if in future if I would like to regenerate this classes again I should do that routine work again.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** (after seeing your code sample): Technically speaking, your code does not have a `Header` *property*, it has a `Header` *field*. This is an important difference, since [you cannot specify fields in an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115114/why-cant-c-sharp-interfaces-contain-fields). However, using the method described below, you can add properties to your classes that return the field values.

---

> Is it possible to define such member in interface?

No, interface names cannot be dynamic. Anyway, such an interface would not be very useful. If you had an instance of class `ISomeRequestClass`, what name would you use to access that property?

You can, however, use explicit interface implementation:

```
interface ISomeRequestClass {
    string Header { get; set; }
    string ClassName1 { get; set; }
}

class SomeClass : ISomeRequestClass {
     string Header { ... }

     string SomeClass1 { ... }

     // new: explicit interface implementation
     string ISomeRequestClass.ClassName1 {
          get { return SomeClass1; }
          set { SomeClass1 = value; }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could define your interface more generally:

```
interface ISomeRequestClass {
  string HeaderProp {get; set;}
  string Prop {get; set;}
}
```

And your concrete classes could be extended (in an extra code file) by mapping interface members to class fields like so:

```
public partial class SimpleRequest : ISomeRequestClass
{
  public string HeaderProp
  {
    get
    {
      return Header;
    }
    set
    {
      Header = value;
    }
  }

  public string Prop
  {
    get
    {
      return SimpleRequest1;
    }
    set
    {
      SimpleRequest1= value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside for a moment the naming of your classes and properties.

If you're looking to create an interface with a property relevant to your specific +1 type, you have a couple of options.

**Use a base class for your +1's**

If both of your +1 classes inherit from the same base class you can use this in your interface definition:

```
public interface IFoo
{
 [...]
 PlusOneBaseType MyPlusOneObject{get;set;}
}
```

**Create a generic property on your interface**

This method allows you to specify the type for the +1 property as a generic parameter:

```
public interface IFoo<TPlusOneType>
{
 [...]
 TPlusOneType MyPlusOneObject{get;set;}
}
```

Which you might use like:

```
public class SimpleRequest : IFoo<SimpleRequest1>
{
 [...]
}
```

**Update**

Given that your classes are partial classes, you could always create a second (non machine generated) version of the partial class that impliments your interface.

Comment: Please see my question edit. This classes doesn't has an base class, but they are partial.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned svcutil so I assume you are using these classes as WCF DataContracts?

If that is the case then you could make use the `name` property of `DataMemberAttribute`.

```
interface IRequest 
{
    string Header { get; set; }
    string Request1 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class SimpleRequest : IRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="SimpleRequest1"]
    public string Request1 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class ComplexRequest : IRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="ComplexRequest1"]
    public string Request1 { get; set; }
}
```

If you are concerned giving yourself more work when you regenerate the code at some point in the future, then I recommend you write a PowerShell script to do this transformation automatically.  After all svcutil is just a script written by some guy at Microsoft.  It is not magic or "correct" or "standard".  Your script can make a call to scvutil and then make a few quick changes to the resulting file.

**EDIT** (After seeing your edit)

You are already using `MessageBodyMemberAttribute`'s `Name` property so just change this:

```
public string SimpleRequest1;
```

To

```
public string Request1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need *these classes* to have a common interface? I'd be tempted to instead create a *wrapper* interface (or just a concrete class) which could then use reflection to access the fields in question:

```
// TODO: Make this class implement an appropriate new interface if you want
// to, for mocking purposes.
public sealed class RequestWrapper<TRequest, TMessage>
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo headerField;
    private static readonly FieldInfo messageField;

    static RequestWrapper()
    {
        // TODO: Validation
        headerField = typeof(TRequest).GetField("Header");
        messageField = typeof(TRequest).GetField(typeof(TRequest).Name + "1");
    }

    private readonly TRequest;

    public RequestWrapper(TRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string) headerField.GetValue(request); }
        set { headerField.SetValue(request, value); }
    }

    public TMessage Message
    {
        get { return (TMessage) messageField.GetValue(request); }
        get { messageField.SetValue(request, value); }
    }
}
```

You could use expression trees to build delegates for this if the reflection proves too slow, but I'd stick to a simple solution to start with.

The advantage of this is that you only need to write this code once - but it does mean creating a wrapper around the real request objects, which the partial class answers don't.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Actually, you point me at the way I partly implemented at the moment. It also use reflection. The issue I ran is how can I create new this common objects using reflection?

Comment: @kseen: Well we'd need to know more about the context... you can use `Type.MakeGenericType` and then create an instance, but what do you *know* at that point? Do you know the type?