# What do you use an interface-level constant for?

Tags: interface, constants

I was [arguing with somebody](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/342368/65755) whether it is okay to put constants into an interface. Some languages support that, while others don't. I like the idea to put some non-configurable, but not necessarily implementation related constants to interfaces, so I don't have to inject them by instantiation or care too much about them. Be aware that I am not talking about totally constant interfaces, which is a known anti-pattern. I found that [somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115114/why-cant-c-sharp-interfaces-contain-fields#comment2052134_2115550) likes this feature too. Can you tell me more about the preconditions and/or constraints of this feature, or just when do you think it is a good practice to use them?

Comment: This question is better for another Stack Exchange Q&A Site.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I don't think so. I mean there are many theoretical/best practice problems discussed here too. So I think this question is okay on either this site or on a few other stack exchange sites too, but I decided to put it here, because this site has the most viewers and I think this is an important question. For example if I'd add a short java example code and the java tag I guess you would not have any problem with it...