# Interface inheritance. Does not implement interface error

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a problem with using inherited interface. I will explain my problem on example below. Let's say I have Interface `IFlyable`:

```
public interface IFlyable
{
    IVerticalSpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```

It contains `IVerticalSpeed` interface. I created another interface called `ISpeed` which inherits from `IVerticalSpeed` interface:

```
public interface ISpeed : IVerticalSpeed
{
    int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

In next step I created a class `Fly` which implement `IFlyable` interface:

```
public class Fly : IFlyable
{
    public IVerticalSpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is fine... but what if I wanted to replace `IVerticalSpeed` interface to `ISpeed` interface which inherits from `IVerticalSpeed` interface?

```
public class Fly : IFlyable
{
    public ISpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that everything should be fine because my `ISpeed` interface is `IVertialSpeed` interface + anything that `ISpeed` interface contatins. But that is not right. I get error which says: "Fly does not implement interface member IFlyable.Speed (...). Why?

Comment: you dont show IVerticalSpeed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't C# interfaces contain fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115114/why-cant-c-sharp-interfaces-contain-fields)

Comment: @Seabizkit - No, but that shouldn't matter. `interface IVerticalSpeed {}` is enough.

Comment: at Adam, no , more info helps. I cant not see if IVerticalSpeed  has IVerticalSpeed  as a property.... odd yes but so is the question, so asking people to help with limited info doesn't paint the whole picture. So the answer would be then that `Fly` no longer implements  `IVerticalSpeed` as a property as denoted by 'IFlyable'

Answer (score 4):

All answers show you possible solutions but none actually answer the important question here:

> I thought that everything should be fine because my `ISpeed` interface is `IVertialSpeed` interface + anything that `ISpeed` interface contatins. But that is not right. I get error which says: "Fly does not implement interface member `IFlyable.Speed` (...). **Why?**

You've said it yourself. `ISpeed` is an `IVerticalSpeed`, but not all `IVerticalSpeed`s are `ISpeed`s so you are not satisfying the contract at all.

What would happen if your code was allowed and I wanted to do the following:

```
public interface IMyOtherSpeed: IVerticalSpeed { ... }
IFlyable myFly = new Fly();
IMyOtherSpeed mySpeed = new MyOtherSpeed();

myFly.Speed = mySpeed; //Runtime error, mySpeed is not an ISpeed?!?
```

You see the issue now? You'd be breaking the interface's contract, becuase your class only accepts `ISpeed` when it should accept *any* `IVerticalSpeed`.

Comment: Another way to put the emphasis: the contract is broken by the `set`, the OP was reasoning about the `get` part.

Answer (score 2):

If you use generics you can do something like

```
public interface IFlyable<out T> : where T IVerticalSpeed
{ T Speed {get;set;} }
```

Then in your class you would do something like

```
public class Fly : IFlyable<SomeSpeedClass>
{
  public SomeSpeedClass Speed{get;set}
}
```

Comment: Do you think of an airplane as an airplane of vertical speed? Just because its possible to do with generics doesn't mean it should. This particular example seems like a bad fit for genercis, to be honest.

Comment: @InBetween what would the best approach for this? Because the `Fly` class has to implement `IFlyable` interface but he wants an instance of `ISpeed` returned in the Speed property instead of an `IVerticalSpeed` instance.

Comment: Without context I wouldn't be able to answer what the best approach is. But its reasonable to expect that `IFlyable` will have similar properties for `HorizontalSpeed`, `HorizontalAcceleration`, `VerticalAcceleration`, etc. Are you going to create an `IFlyable<T1, T2, T3, etc>` interface? And lets not even get started on how to deal with generic type variance... it all gets very messy very fast. Generics shouldn't be a solution just to make the type system work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
public class Fly : IFlyable
{
    public ISpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```

You should match the `IFlyable` interface

```
public class Fly : IFlyable
{
    public IVerticalSpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Interfaces are not inheritance, must be matched exactly.

Edit: Let me rephrase, interfaces that implementing other interfaces is not inheritance, hence the error. Interfaces must me matched exactly, that's is why it raises the error (ISpeed != IVerticalSpeed)

Comment: upvoting @InBetween because it is more clear, although both answers try to answer the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because your property's **signature** must stay 100% the same. You can implement a new property, as a workaround. But it has it's limitations, too.

You *can* do this if your inheritance would work both ways. You already know, all `ISpeed`s are `IVerticalSpeed`s. But that's not the case the other way round. Not all `IVerticalSpeed`s are `ISpeed`s. So we can give your class another method, but it will face a problem at exactly that point:

```
  public interface IVerticalSpeed
  {
    int Value { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IFlyable
  {
    IVerticalSpeed Speed { get; set; }
  }

  public interface ISpeed : IVerticalSpeed
  {
    int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
  }

  public class Fly : IFlyable
  {
    public ISpeed Speed { get; set; }

    IVerticalSpeed IFlyable.Speed
    {
      get
      {
        return this.Speed;
      }
      set
      {
        // Wow, wait, you want to SET an IVerticalSpeed,
        // but not every IVerticalSpeed is an ISpeed... what now?
        // this.Speed = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

This is not a problem of code, this is a design problem. What do you want to do, if someone sets an `IVerticalSpeed` to your `Fly`? Because your interface says that's allowed. Maybe you don't want setters?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown `IVerticalSpeed`, but if you have control of it consider

```
public interface IFlyable<out TSpeed>
    where TSpeed : IVerticalSpeed
{
    TSpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```

then implemented in `Fly` like this

```
public class Fly : IFlyable<ISpeed>
{
    public ISpeed Speed { get; set; }
}
```